# iteration through dataclass with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, iteration, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass that contains different type of variables and i d like to print couples of them using list comprehension to iterate through. while i dont get any error my output is a generator object rather than the content. I tried replacing ( ) with [ ] but no difference.

**edited answer with correction thanks to suggestions below**

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import numpy as np

@dataclass
class Node :
    name : str
    surround_node : list
    weight : np.array

    def print_node (n):
        print (f"the node {n.name} has {len(n.surround_node)} neighbours :", end="") 
        print (",".join(f"({v}, {p})"
            for v, p in zip(n.surround_node, n.weight)))        
       
Node_1 = Node("N1", ["N2", "N3"], np.array([1, 2]))
Node_2 = Node("N2", ["N1", "N3", "N4"], np.array([2, 4, 8]))
Node_3 = Node("N3", ["N1", "N2"], np.array([3, 4]))
Node_4 = Node("N4", ["N2"], np.array([1]))

# print(Node_1)
# print(Node_2)
# print(Node_3)
Node_2.print_node()
``
the output for node N2 has 3 neighbors : (N1, 2), (N3, 4), (N4, 8)
```

Comment: You set `surround_node` to a list of *names*, not a list of `Node` instances.

Comment: You should also write `Node_2.print_node()`, not `Node.print_node(Node_2)`.

Comment: confused about these, on both separately i get an an attribute error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name' for surround_node  and AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'weight' respectively. any suggestion on how to declare them?

Comment: See my first comment. `"N1"` is a string, not an instance of `Node` that has a `name` attribute.

Comment: got it thanks a lot - i edited the question with working code.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
        print (",".join(f"({v.name}, {p.weight})") for v, p in zip(n.surround_node, n.weight))
```

You want

```
        print (",".join(f"({v.name}, {p.weight})" for v, p in zip(n.surround_node, n.weight)))
```

Your IDE would help you to understand the meaning of what you wrote
if you turned the one-liner into a couple of appropriately indented lines.

```
        print (",".join(f"({v.name}, {p.weight})"
                        for v, p in zip(n.surround_node, n.weight)))
```

which is quite different from

```
        print (",".join(f"({v.name}, {p.weight})")
               for v, p in zip(n.surround_node, n.weight))
```